# Notifications about Public Google API keys, while they are restricted

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, api-key

The last couple of days, I'm getting e-mails from the Google Cloud Platform telling me they found a Publicly Accassible Google API key.

Every time I check, the key is used on a site for Google Maps and is restricted in the dashboard via a URL (or multiple). So I don't think it's a problem. People can use the key in their project, but won't be able to benefit from it since it's restricted. Right?

So I'm wondering why I get these notifications this week (1 every day).
As far as I know, I need the key to simply load the Google Maps Javascript like this:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****`
So this key will always be "publicly accessible" when looking at the page source in the browser.

I don't like to just ignore these e-mails, because I might miss something. But in this case, I can't seem to figure out what to do.

Comment: You better contact Google Support as this is not reproducible. We don't know what key is involved, how it is configured/restricted, and what the email exactly says, etc.

Comment: I received one today and one of my clients received one yesterday.  Keys are restricted and always have been.  Think it is a Google glitch.

Comment: I believe those are automated emails, if you're sure that you have no usage on those websites, or that you have properly restricted your API keys, then you can just ignore it since you will not be billed by those. "Publicly accessible" means that your key was found on a public site where it is viewable by others. I do not know the details of where your key was found, but the most common place people expose their API keys are in a code repository like Github or here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Yrll The URL that was mentioned in the e-mail was just linking to a page on a website we created for that customer. The site contains an overview of all their offices. The link pointed to a detail-page of 1 of the officelocations, which had a Google Maps shown on the page. As do all detail-pages of the locations on that site.

You can only see the key when you view the source in the browser, and that key is restricted by the domain it's used on (the domain of that customer). 

I guess, like Marko1 said, it's a Ggoogle glitch.

Comment: Oh okayy then that means your key is indeed in a publicly accessible website. being "publicly accessible" does not necessarily mean "unrestricted". I guess its their way of reminding project owners to always secure their API keys, but since it's already restricted, you don't have anything to worry about.